# Not able to run php script from cron

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cron, wget

I am running LAMP system on ubuntu 14.04. I have an rss feed using php which runs every 1 hour and MySQL stores data. My php file used to run perfectly using php in cron some 15 days but its not working anymore

My cron is as below

```
0 * * * *  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/rss.php >/dev/null
```

My php script is working perfectly from browser(firefox/chrome)

When I run the php script using wget in cron it works fine

```
0 * * * *  wget http://www.mywebsite.com/rss.php >/dev/null
```

Comment: What do you get by running `cd / && /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/rss.php`?

Comment: Hi Daniil, The output for the above command is that php script tries to run for 5-6 seconds and i again see the root@tb:/# screen. My php code atleast runs for 6-7 minutes when run from browser or wget and I have txt files which I write from ph pscript  to see if the script has run. The php script is not running

Comment: Can we see your script? PHP CLI configuration is different with web one

Comment: my php code is 1500 lines

Comment: Do you have something web-based ($_SERVER varaibles), something that rely on PATHES (e.g. includes?)

Comment: No there are no includes. nor any server variables. The whole RSS was working last month but then I increased the size of the VM with snapshot and it stopped working. I dont there is any problem with php code since it is running in wget perfectly. There seems to be some permision or path problem

Comment: try to put `root ` before  `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: I tried putting root before ./usr/bin/php but that is also not working. When I see the processes in top php runs for 4-5 seconds but it is not clicking apache or cli after that

Comment: can you post your code somewhere (e.g. pastebin, github gist)?

Comment: Daniil, I have found an interesting thing. when i type command which php. I get /usr/bin/php. When I type command php rss.php in command line in directory /var/www/html/, it works.. But when I type php /var/www/html/rss.php  in command line in / directory, it does not work. So I think it is some sort of path problem

Comment: Hey Daniill. I have put my code guthub gist. Here is the link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/102b45ce08925132c566

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87723/discussion-between-jayesh-duggal-and-daniil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is using relatives pathes.

When you open this script in a browser it tries to find files in `/var/www/html/`.

When you do it in the cron it tries to find files in `/`.

Put this in the beginning of your script:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Now change every relative include or opener:

```
include ROOT . "db.php"
```

...

```
    if (($handle = fopen(ROOT . "tbcatlist.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
```